# Azure deployment: Configuring database dependency throws error "Failed to configure NuGet packages"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-deployment, azure-appservice

I am trying to publish my.NetCore WebAPI with SQL Server database to Azure. - configuring database dependency throws the error "Error Failed to configure NuGet packages. Error Failed to configure dependency Azure SQL Database mssql1."

May I know what causes this error.

[image]

Comment: _ NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageReferenceRollbackException_ seems relevant... are you trying to add a .NET Core package to a .NET Framework based project?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I get this error only while deploying to azure, my local setup works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** Although it known  restarting Visual Studio sometimes resolves the issue.

If used, packages.config is typically located in a project root. It's automatically created when the first NuGet operation is run, but can also be created manually before running any commands such as nuget restore.

Projects that use PackageReference do not use packages.config.

Updating Visual Studio to VS 2019 16.11.5

Try to upgrade the NuGet Package Manager to 3.6 and restarted.

> Package Manager Console( Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package
> Manager Console)

Comment: Hi, Yes my project uses PackageReference. Do not have package.config in root folder. I already updated Visual Studio  to VS 2019 16.11.5 and using NuGet Package Manager 5.11.0.

Comment: When I untick Nuget Packages while deployment, API gets deployed to Azure. But not sure if that will be a good option and won't cause any problem along the way.

Comment: Sure, you could go for that now, I am trying to check more relevant things- Please let me know if any error pops up,